# I have implemented readlines in my python code. How do i make it parse each URLs in the list?

Tags: python, database

I wrote a data miner in python3 where i have a list of urls in text file to parse and extract specific information

```
import requests
import urllib
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 
def news(): 
    linksFile = open('list.txt','r')
    linksList = linksFile.readlines()
    for link in linksList:
        url = link 

    # the target we want to open     
      
    #open with GET method 
    resp=requests.get(url)
      
    #http_respone 200 means OK status    
    f = open("Websites.txt", "a")
    if resp.status_code==200: 
        print("Successfully opened the web page") 
        print("Successfully saved to text file :-\n") 
      
        # we need a parser,Python built-in HTML parser is enough . 
        soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')     
  
        # l is the list which contains all the text i.e news  
        l=soup.find("div",{"class":"m-exhibitor-entry__item__body__contacts__additional__website"}) 
      
        #now we want to print only the text part of the anchor. 
        #find all the elements of a, i.e anchor 
        for i in l.findAll("a"): 
            f.write(i.text)
            f.write("\n")            
    else: 
        print("Error") 
          
news()
```

. However, when i run the code, it only grabs and parses the last url in the list (newlines), ignoring all the other urls.

I want it to parse each url, one after the other, and output the result as it does the last url.

For this example, see below list of url.

https://www.enlit-europe.com/exhibitors/precept
https://www.enlit-europe.com/exhibitors/prince-kunststof-infra

Comment: You need to indent the code beneath the line url = link. Currently it is only performed once, after the for loop has finished, but you need it to execute within the for loop.

Comment: What's the reason for `url = link`? Either use `link` in the rest of the loop, or use `for url in linksList:`

Comment: Hello @Lee-xp, thanks for your input. But i'm a bit lost with the solutions provided. If any can kindly re-write the intended line and comment the code. Super grateful

Comment: Hi @Barmar can you kindly paste the finished code for it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code needs to be part of the `for link in linksList:`, not just the assignment to `url`.

There's no need to have both `link` and `url` variables. Just use `link` in the `requests.get()` call.

```
def news(): 
    linksFile = open('list.txt','r')
    linksList = linksFile.readlines()
    for link in linksList:
        # the target we want to open     
          
        #open with GET method 
        resp=requests.get(link)
          
        #http_respone 200 means OK status    
        f = open("Websites.txt", "a")
        if resp.status_code==200: 
            print("Successfully opened the web page") 
            print("Successfully saved to text file :-\n") 
          
            # we need a parser,Python built-in HTML parser is enough . 
            soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')     
      
            # l is the list which contains all the text i.e news  
            l=soup.find("div",{"class":"m-exhibitor-entry__item__body__contacts__additional__website"}) 
          
            #now we want to print only the text part of the anchor. 
            #find all the elements of a, i.e anchor 
            for i in l.findAll("a"): 
                f.write(i.text)
                f.write("\n")            
        else: 
            print("Error")
```

Comment: A million thanks @Barmar. It worked now. You made my day!